# plt.imshow() returns TypeError when run with certain images, but not with others

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

**I'm writing an image optimisation algorythm** (I know it's horribly inefficient, it's just my 1st attempt), and here's what I currently have. The directory of the project looks like this:

[image: Directory]

`image_encoding.py` takes an image and encodes it **using the following logic**:

```
if the pixel is new, it encodes its RGB value
else, it encodes the index of a pixel with the same color
```

If you need more insight, here's my **code** for `image_encoding.py`(it writes the **encoded image into** `image_code.txt`):

```
# imports

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

# reading the image and displaying it

image = mpimg.imread('./100x150.jpg')
size = [image.shape[0], image.shape[1]]
print(f'size of the image: {size}')
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()

# flattening the image for further processing

new_image = []

for imgline in image:
    for pixel in imgline:
        new_image.append(list(pixel))

image = new_image

# encodind the image

print('started encoding')

image_coding = []

# for a simple 2x2 image of a black square, image_coding will look like this:
# [ [ 255, 255, 255 ], 0, 0, 0 ]

i = 0

for pixel in image:

    i += 1

    print(f'{str(i / len(image) * 100)[:5]}% done', end='\r')

    if pixel not in image_coding:
        image_coding.append(pixel)
    else:
        image_coding.append(image_coding.index(pixel))

# write the image coding into a file

print('writing image coding into image_code.txt')

f = open("image_code.txt", "w")
f.write(str(image_coding))
f.close()
f = open("image_code.txt", "a")
f.write(f'\n{size}')
f.close()

print('image successfully encoded into image_code.txt')
```

Then, the `image_code.txt` file will look like this:

```
[[67, 58, 41], [68, 59, 42], [70, 61, 44], [71, 62, 45], [72, 63, 46], 4, 4, 3, [75, 66, 49], 8, 8, 8, [73, 64, 47], 3, 2, [67, 60, 41], [66, 59, 40], [73, 68, 48], [82, 76, 60], [95, 89, 77], [113, 106, 100], [131, 123, 121], [137, 128, 133], [134, 124, 132], [125, 115, 126], [118, 108, 119], [105, 95, 104], [88, 78, 86], [77, 68, 73], [76, 67, 68], [85, 76, 77], [93, 88, 85], [86, 82, 79], [83, 82, 77], [77, 74, 69], [66, 63, 54], [61, 59, 47], [64, 62, 47], [66, 63, 48], [65, 62, 45], [78, 73, 54], [75, 70, 51], 41, [72, 67, 48], [70, 62, 49], [78, 70, 57], [82, 74, 63], [73, 65, 52], [76, 68, 55], [77, 70, 54], [77, 69, 56], 48, 48, [80, 72, 59], [86, 78, 67], [92, 84, 73], [89, 80, 71], [86, 77, 68], [81, 72, 63], [76, 67, 58], [71, 62, 55], [69, 60, 53], [67, 58, 51], [67, 59, 48], [68, 56, 42], [67, 56, 38], [65, 54, 36], [64, 53, 35], [66, 55, 37], [70, 59, 41], [75, 64, 46], [78, 67, 49], [79, 68, 50], 71, 71, [76, 65, 47], 70, [74, 63, 45], [73, 62, 44], 78, 3, 4, 12, 12, 2, 1, [66, 57, 40], [65, 56, 39], [62, 53, 36], [64, 55, 38], 89, 88, [59, 50, 33], [58, 49, 32], 93, 93, [57, 50, 31], 96, 96, [56, 49, 30], 1, [69, 60, 43], 3, 12, [74, 65, 48], 104, 104, 12, 104, 104, 104, 104, 12, 3, 101, [67, 60, 42], 16, [73, 68, 49], [83, 77, 63], [96, 89, 79], [115, 107, 104], [134, 125, 126], [143, 133, 141], [142, 132, 141], [140, 129, 143], [134, 123, 137], [121, 111, 122], [103, 93, 102], [90, 80, 88], [87, 78, 81], [93, 84, 87], [99, 93, 93], [95, 91, 90], [93, 92, 90], [89, 85, 82], [79, 76, 69], [73, 70, 61], [73, 71, 59], [73, 69, 57], [69, 66, 51], [78, 72, 56], [76, 70, 54], 140, [75, 69, 53], [71, 63, 50], 48, [79, 71, 60], 44, 48, 50, 45, 50, 48, [79, 71, 58], [84, 76, 65], [89, 81, 70], [90, 81, 72], [88, 79, 70], [84, 75, 66], [80, 71, 64], [76, 67, 60], [73, 64, 57], 60, [71, 61, 52], [72, 60, 46], 69, 65, 66, 66, [68, 57, 39], [71, 60, 42], 77, 70, 70, 77, 78, [72, 61, 43], 170, 69, [69, 58, 40], 3, 12, 104, 8, 4, 101, 87, [63, 54, 37], 88, 89, 86, 87, 88, 92, 93, 93, 96, 96, 96, 99, 101, 3, 12, 8, [76, 67, 50], [77, 68, 51], 204, 204, 8, 204, 204, 8, 104, 4, 2, [68, 61, 43], [64, 57, 41], [69, 63, 51], [79, 72, 62], [92, 85, 79], [111, 102, 103], [132, 123, 128], [146, 136, 147], [152, 141, 155], [158, 147, 164], [153, 142, 159], [140, 129, 145], [123, 112, 126], [107, 97, 108], [99, 89, 97], [100, 90, 98], [103, 97, 101], [103, 98, 102], [106, 101, 105], [104, 100, 101], [96, 92, 91], [92, 87, 84], [89, 84, 78], [84, 80, 71], [77, 73, 62], [81, 75, 63], [79, 73, 61], [82, 74, 61], 153, 144, 47, [76, 66, 54], [69, 59, 47], [74, 64, 52], [75, 65, 55], 249, 249, 249, [79, 69, 59], [85, 75, 66], [90, 80, 71], [93, 82, 76], [92, 81, 75], [91, 80, 74], [88, 77, 73], [84, 73, 69], [80, 69, 65], [77, 66, 62], [75, 65, 56], [76, 64, 50], 78, 179, 68, 67, 68, 169, 69, 176, 170, 69, 179, 169, 65, 68, 68, 4, 8, [78, 69, 52], [80, 71, 54], [79, 70, 53], 104, 0, 88, [60, 51, 34], 187, 0, 101, 87, [61, 52, 35], 92, 288, [58, 51, 32], 296, 96, 96, 2, 4, 104, 204, 282, 284, 284, 284, 205, 282, 282, 282, 204, 104, 4, [70, 63, 47], [63, 55, 42], [65, 58, 48], [70, 63, 55], [80, 72, 69], [98, 89, 92], [121, 111, 119], [142, 132, 143], [155, 144, 160], [167, 156, 173], [163, 152, 169], [154, 143, 160], [137, 126, 142], [119, 109, 120], [107, 97, 106], [103, 93, 101], [104, 94, 102], [106, 99, 106], [112, 107, 113], [115, 110, 116], [113, 108, 112], [111, 105, 107], [107, 101, 101], [99, 94, 91], [91, 86, 82], [90, 83, 77], [84, 77, 69], 158, 146, [69, 61, 48], 44, 248, [70, 60, 48], [70, 60, 50], 348, [72, 59, 50], 348, [73, 60, 51], [77, 67, 57], [88, 75, 67], [93, 83, 74], [97, 84, 78], [96, 85, 79], [97, 83, 80], [94, 83, 79], [93, 79, 76], [87, 76, 72], [85, 71, 68], [83, 70, 62], [79, 67, 53], 75, 176, 169, 68, 68, 169, 69, 170, 170, 69, 179, 65, 68, [251, 214, 185], [253, 217, 191], [255, 222, 196], [255, 224, 200], [255, 224, 199], [255, 222, 197], [251, 219, 196], [250, 218, 195], [255, 224, 203], 2857, [255, 227, 206], [255, 228, 207], [255, 228, 209], [254, 229, 209], [254, 227, 208], 2857, [247, 212, 182], [255, 226, 190], [255, 223, 187], [239, 205, 168], [243, 211, 173], [255, 234, 198], [245, 219, 186], [197, 172, 142], [59, 34, 12], 2433, 2468, [44, 24, 17], [62, 43, 37], [40, 22, 18], [37, 19, 17], [62, 49, 43], 823, 49, 2786, 2883, 2884, [87, 79, 68], 2985, [85, 76, 67], 158, [89, 80, 73], [95, 86, 79], [101, 92, 87], [104, 95, 90], [104, 94, 92], [102, 92, 90], [100, 91, 86], [87, 80, 70], [85, 79, 67], 240, 2798, 1714, [84, 78, 56], 1714, 1603, 1605, 1609, [70, 64, 42], 1609, 3006, 1609, 1708, 1605, [77, 71, 49], 1703, 3001, 1613, [89, 78, 58], [88, 77, 57], [76, 63, 46], 1971, [38, 21, 11], 2136, [43, 26, 18], [42, 23, 16], [53, 32, 27], [49, 26, 20], [26, 4, 0], 2532, [66, 40, 23], [134, 109, 89], [178, 154, 130], [197, 166, 137], [202, 157, 118], [216, 163, 121], [216, 164, 124], [216, 167, 127], [224, 176, 138], 2442, [227, 183, 148], [235, 191, 156], [239, 196, 162], [243, 202, 170], [249, 208, 176], [251, 211, 176], [251, 208, 174], [250, 207, 172], [254, 211, 176], [255, 216, 181], [251, 215, 183], [251, 216, 188], [253, 218, 190], 2851, [255, 222, 195], 3052, [253, 219, 194], [249, 217, 192], [253, 221, 198], [253, 223, 199], [254, 223, 202], [252, 224, 202], [252, 224, 203], [250, 223, 202], [250, 221, 203], [251, 220, 199], [241, 204, 177], [255, 227, 194], [255, 231, 194], [249, 214, 174], [239, 206, 163], [242, 210, 169], [245, 217, 177], [246, 220, 185], [156, 132, 104], [70, 48, 27], 2433, [35, 15, 8], [43, 24, 20], [26, 8, 8], [31, 12, 14], [53, 38, 35], [64, 54, 44], 47, 46, 46, 46, 2987, 57, [85, 76, 69], 2794, [87, 78, 73], [93, 84, 79], [99, 89, 87], 2993, [106, 96, 95], 3093, [106, 96, 94], [93, 86, 76], [89, 83, 71], [84, 78, 66], 241, 2601, 1602, 2602, 1803, 1690, 2193, 2189, 1907, 1990, 1606, 1690, 1297, 1715, 1296, 2580, 1694, [97, 89, 68], [79, 68, 48], [49, 38, 20], [28, 15, 0], [26, 12, 0], [39, 22, 12], [46, 29, 19], [45, 27, 17], [42, 20, 9], [43, 19, 7], [33, 7, 0], [55, 28, 9], [129, 98, 77], [184, 154, 128], [196, 165, 137], [201, 165, 133], [202, 154, 116], [217, 166, 123], [217, 168, 127], [214, 166, 126], [223, 177, 141], [232, 188, 153], [237, 194, 160], [243, 200, 166], [242, 201, 169], [243, 204, 173], [246, 207, 176], [249, 210, 179], [251, 210, 178], 3043, [250, 210, 175], [250, 209, 177], [250, 213, 184], [248, 211, 184], [247, 210, 184], [249, 213, 187], [252, 218, 193], [254, 220, 195], 3054, [251, 216, 194], [248, 216, 193], 3156, [249, 217, 196], [248, 217, 196], [248, 215, 196], [246, 213, 194], [244, 211, 192], [245, 210, 190], [252, 215, 188], [253, 214, 183], [246, 208, 172], [250, 212, 173], [255, 219, 175], [241, 207, 162], [235, 202, 159], [252, 220, 181], [255, 229, 195], [136, 109, 82], [48, 21, 2], [33, 9, 0], [28, 8, 1], [19, 1, 0], [33, 17, 17], [56, 41, 36], [65, 53, 41], [78, 66, 52], 2177, 2420, 146, 2317, [82, 73, 66], 159, 159, [84, 75, 68], 441, 2893, 2994, 3095, [108, 98, 96], [108, 99, 94], [95, 87, 76], [91, 83, 70], 2884, 153, 154, 242, 2515, 50, 2694, 2688, 1623, 47, [76, 68, 57], 48, 2886, 2884, 2886, 2278, 1621, 2182, [100, 90, 78], [50, 41, 26], [37, 27, 15], [45, 33, 21], [39, 27, 15], 1940, 1448, [30, 13, 0], 2264, [44, 20, 0], [76, 49, 20], [132, 101, 72], [179, 144, 114], [199, 163, 131], [208, 169, 138], [218, 175, 143], [217, 171, 137], [221, 176, 137], 3136, [222, 176, 140], [220, 176, 141], [224, 181, 146], [234, 191, 157], 3139, [235, 194, 162], [236, 195, 163], [236, 197, 166], [237, 198, 167], [240, 201, 170], [244, 205, 172], [247, 208, 175], [248, 209, 180], [249, 209, 184], [250, 209, 189], [251, 210, 190], [250, 212, 191], [251, 215, 193], [252, 217, 195], 2954, [252, 220, 199], [250, 218, 197], [251, 219, 198], 3257, [253, 218, 198], [252, 215, 196], [249, 211, 192], [246, 208, 189], [244, 206, 185], [244, 208, 182], [245, 210, 180], [246, 210, 178], [245, 205, 170], [241, 199, 161], [239, 196, 154], [242, 197, 155], [243, 200, 158], [255, 213, 175], [233, 195, 159], [144, 110, 82], [49, 23, 0], [28, 7, 0], [40, 24, 9], [42, 32, 22], [50, 38, 26], 749, [108, 91, 71], [111, 95, 79], [89, 77, 61], 1922, 2415, [78, 71, 61], [80, 73, 63], [77, 68, 59], 58, [87, 77, 67], [91, 81, 71], [94, 84, 75], [97, 87, 78], [102, 91, 85], [106, 96, 87], 2918, [98, 84, 71], [93, 79, 66], [87, 73, 60], 2317, 2317, 2317, [79, 70, 61], 3303, [78, 69, 60], 3288, 59, [75, 66, 57], 59, 158, 56, [91, 82, 73], [101, 92, 83], [105, 96, 87], [97, 88, 79], [57, 47, 37], [37, 27, 17], [44, 34, 24], [52, 42, 32], [46, 34, 22], [34, 22, 8], [30, 14, 0], [41, 25, 2], [55, 35, 10], [77, 54, 23], [121, 92, 58], [168, 135, 100], [199, 160, 127], [207, 167, 132], [211, 166, 135], [215, 170, 137], [216, 171, 138], 3236, [223, 179, 144], 3334, [222, 179, 144], [225, 182, 147], 3238, [242, 199, 165], 3240, 3240, [235, 196, 165], 3243, 3244, 3141, [245, 209, 177], [246, 209, 182], [247, 206, 184], [248, 207, 189], [249, 208, 190], 3261, [249, 214, 194], 3158, 3256, [250, 219, 198], 3063, 3255, 3255, [254, 219, 199], [254, 216, 197], [252, 214, 195], [253, 212, 194], 3251, [245, 211, 186], [243, 212, 184], [245, 210, 182], 3141, [241, 197, 162], [239, 194, 155], [242, 193, 153], [242, 195, 153], [246, 201, 160], [254, 212, 174], [216, 180, 146], [127, 98, 68], [56, 35, 8], [49, 32, 12], [62, 51, 33], [63, 50, 33], [97, 79, 57], [126, 105, 84], [127, 110, 90], [98, 85, 68], 1921, 1623, [77, 70, 60], 3287, 3303, 46, [89, 76, 67], 1317, 3291, 355, 3293, 1319, [97, 83, 70], [97, 81, 66], [92, 76, 61], [88, 72, 57], [77, 68, 61], [78, 69, 62], [81, 72, 65], 2794, 2794, 3186, 3402, 159, 3400, 3400, 3087, [93, 84, 77], [101, 92, 85], 724, [108, 99, 92], 157, 3317, [31, 21, 11], [36, 26, 16], [39, 29, 19], [48, 36, 24], [48, 36, 22], [45, 29, 13], [62, 46, 23], [86, 66, 41], [120, 97, 66], [165, 136, 104], [196, 163, 128], [209, 170, 137], [208, 167, 135], 3330, [213, 168, 135], 3332, [221, 177, 142], [226, 182, 147], 3038, [226, 183, 149], [228, 185, 151], 3238, 3040, [234, 193, 161], 3440, 3342, 3243, 3244, [244, 205, 174], [245, 208, 179], [247, 210, 183], [245, 207, 184], [245, 209, 187], [247, 211, 189], [248, 213, 191], 3156, [248, 218, 194], [248, 220, 196], [249, 221, 197], [250, 222, 198], 3455, [250, 220, 196], 2954, [253, 218, 196], [254, 218, 196], [255, 218, 197], [254, 219, 197], [247, 216, 195], [247, 217, 193], [245, 213, 188], [242, 207, 179], [239, 198, 166], [236, 193, 158], [235, 189, 153], [235, 190, 151], [243, 199, 160], [253, 213, 177], [252, 216, 182], [183, 152, 121], [78, 52, 25], [42, 22, 0], [63, 46, 26], [72, 55, 35], [111, 91, 67], [133, 113, 89], [133, 116, 96], [101, 88, 71], 248, 1623, 3286, [78, 71, 63], 3186, 2987, 2819, 2819, 834, [89, 78, 72], 258, [96, 83, 75], [95, 81, 68], 1973, [90, 77, 61], [87, 74, 58], 3400, [79, 70, 63], 2794, 2793, [87, 78, 71], 3087, 2794, 3402, 3402, 3402, 2793, 3411, [105, 96, 89], 725, 3414, 159, [35, 25, 16], 3419, 3419, [32, 22, 12], [45, 32, 23], [55, 43, 29], [59, 43, 27], 1052, [114, 94, 69], [146, 123, 92], [180, 151, 119], [195, 162, 129], [200, 161, 128], [204, 163, 131], [213, 168, 137], [216, 171, 140], [217, 172, 139], [222, 178, 143], [228, 184, 149], [231, 187, 152], [231, 188, 154], 3536, 3238, 3138, 3440, 3440, 3342, 3243, [241, 202, 171], [245, 206, 175], [246, 209, 180], 3149, [250, 214, 190], [249, 214, 192], 3155, 2955, [251, 221, 197], [251, 223, 199], [251, 225, 200], [252, 226, 201], [248, 222, 197], [247, 221, 196], [247, 219, 195], [249, 219, 195], 2954, 3056, [255, 223, 201], [255, 226, 205], 2958, [252, 225, 204], 3063, 3466, [240, 205, 175], [235, 196, 163], [231, 191, 156], [228, 188, 152], [243, 203, 167], [241, 203, 167], [249, 213, 179], [224, 191, 160], [147, 120, 91], [92, 66, 41], [91, 69, 45], [111, 89, 65], [112, 90, 66], [123, 103, 79], [121, 104, 84], [97, 84, 67], 246, 3303, [82, 75, 67], [75, 68, 60], [88, 79, 72], [90, 81, 74], [95, 82, 76], [94, 81, 75], [90, 79, 75], [89, 78, 74], [91, 80, 78], 256, 1230, [95, 82, 66], 1037, 3498, [79, 70, 65], 732, [85, 76, 71], [88, 79, 74], 3603, [86, 77, 72], [84, 75, 70], 732, 3089, 3089, 3603, 441, [102, 93, 88], [118, 109, 104], 629, 60, [32, 22, 13], [51, 41, 31], [60, 50, 41], 1824, [43, 30, 21], 2721, [63, 47, 32], [94, 77, 57], [125, 105, 80], [148, 124, 96], [172, 143, 111], [182, 149, 116], [192, 153, 120], [205, 164, 132], [217, 172, 143], [220, 175, 144], [220, 175, 142], [224, 180, 145], [230, 185, 152], [234, 189, 156], 3238, 3238, [235, 192, 160], [236, 193, 161], [234, 193, 163], [235, 194, 164], 3242, [238, 199, 168], [242, 203, 174], [247, 208, 179], [249, 212, 183], [250, 215, 187], 2953, 3057, [254, 224, 200], [253, 225, 201], [254, 226, 202], [254, 228, 203], 3653, [254, 230, 204], [249, 225, 199], [249, 223, 198], 3657, 3456, 2863, [255, 227, 203], [255, 229, 206], [255, 231, 210], [255, 235, 216], [255, 233, 216], 2960, [250, 222, 200], [246, 214, 189], [239, 205, 177], [233, 198, 168], [229, 193, 161], [230, 194, 160], [236, 200, 166], [240, 205, 173], [246, 213, 180], [227, 196, 167], [168, 139, 109], [121, 91, 63], [116, 90, 63], [108, 84, 58], [111, 91, 66], [115, 98, 78], 3483, [80, 70, 58], 2317, [85, 78, 70], [77, 70, 64], 630, [96, 87, 82], [101, 87, 84], [100, 86, 83], [96, 85, 83], [95, 83, 83], [97, 85, 87], [99, 88, 86], [99, 86, 77], [97, 85, 71], 1321, 1428, [81, 72, 67], 3186, 3602, 3504, 3089, 3504, 3602, 3189, [91, 82, 77], 3411, 3708, 3504, [95, 86, 81], 724, 2893, [60, 51, 44], [47, 37, 28], [55, 45, 35], [58, 48, 39], [40, 30, 21], [37, 24, 15], 2721, 1350, [97, 80, 60], [118, 98, 74], [138, 114, 86], [161, 132, 100], [177, 144, 111], [195, 156, 125], [210, 169, 137], [221, 176, 147], [222, 177, 146], [224, 179, 146], 3038, [231, 186, 153], [235, 190, 157], [236, 193, 159], 3138, [237, 194, 162], 3738, 3641, [236, 195, 165], 3243, 3244, [245, 206, 177], [249, 210, 181], 2948, 3050, 2952, [255, 225, 201], 3749, 3651, 3651, 3555, 3555, 3555, 3554, 3554, 3555, 3652, 2755, [255, 231, 207], [255, 233, 209], [255, 233, 212], [255, 235, 218], 3665, [255, 230, 211], 2958, [251, 223, 201], [247, 217, 191], [241, 210, 182], [236, 205, 176], [221, 188, 157], [238, 205, 174], [232, 199, 168], [234, 201, 170], [249, 216, 185], [214, 181, 150], [143, 110, 79], [102, 73, 43], [103, 79, 51], [103, 83, 58], [118, 101, 81], 964, [87, 77, 65], 3288, 341, [82, 75, 69], [96, 86, 84], 3091, [104, 90, 89], [105, 91, 91], [102, 90, 90], [103, 91, 93], [105, 93, 97], [108, 96, 98], [106, 93, 87], 1419, [100, 87, 78], 1318, 3501, 2317, 3186, 158, 2793, 157, 2989, 56, 3589, [96, 87, 78], [96, 87, 80], 57, 2989, [103, 94, 85], 3504, [48, 39, 30], [52, 42, 33], [42, 32, 23], [43, 32, 26], [33, 23, 14], [33, 20, 11], 2777, [76, 60, 45], [93, 76, 56], [107, 87, 63], [128, 104, 76], [155, 126, 96], 3727, [197, 158, 127], [210, 169, 139], [222, 177, 148], [227, 182, 151], [228, 183, 150], [229, 184, 151], [232, 187, 154], 3735, 3639, [238, 195, 163], 2456, 2456, 2457, [238, 197, 167], [239, 200, 171], 3644, [247, 207, 181], [252, 212, 186], [254, 217, 190], [255, 220, 192], 2953, [253, 221, 196], [252, 220, 195], [250, 220, 194], [249, 219, 193], [245, 218, 191], [244, 217, 190], 3854, [248, 221, 194], [249, 222, 195], [251, 224, 197], 2656, 2660, [255, 228, 203], 3861, 2758, [255, 225, 207], [253, 224, 208], [254, 225, 207], [255, 227, 209], [255, 230, 209], [255, 228, 206], 3553, [247, 220, 193], [235, 205, 177], [239, 210, 180], [232, 201, 172], 3774, [250, 217, 186], 3265, [189, 154, 124], [124, 93, 64], [99, 73, 46], [91, 71, 46], [114, 98, 75], [126, 113, 96], 2079, 2317, [84, 77, 71], [85, 77, 74], [94, 84, 83], [97, 87, 86], [104, 90, 90], [107, 92, 95], [106, 94, 98], [108, 95, 102], [112, 99, 108], [116, 103, 110], [116, 105, 103], [114, 103, 99], [111, 100, 96], [108, 97, 93], 2693, 2693, 146, 46, 2790, 155, 55, 1684, [88, 80, 69], 729, [99, 91, 80], 2985, 54, 729, 2515, [40, 32, 21], [27, 17, 8], [25, 15, 6], [46, 35, 29], [45, 34, 28], 1744, 3279, 1349, [87, 70, 52], [102, 82, 58], [123, 99, 71], [152, 123, 93], [176, 143, 112], [193, 154, 123], [206, 165, 135], 3830, [232, 187, 158], [231, 186, 155], 3734, 3834, 3635, 3639, [239, 196, 164], [239, 195, 166], 3938, 3841, [239, 198, 168], [240, 201, 172], [243, 204, 175], [248, 208, 182], [253, 213, 187], [255, 219, 192], [255, 221, 195], [253, 217, 193], [251, 217, 192], [249, 215, 190], [247, 213, 188], 3364, [241, 209, 184], [242, 208, 183], [239, 207, 182], [246, 212, 187], 3668, 3152, 2854, 2953, [255, 223, 198], 2953, [255, 220, 198], [250, 215, 196], [248, 215, 198], [251, 220, 200], [255, 226, 206], 3763, [255, 236, 213], [255, 233, 210], [255, 229, 204], [254, 228, 201], [235, 208, 179], [234, 204, 176], [242, 211, 182], [248, 214, 186], [249, 214, 184], [206, 169, 140], [130, 96, 68], [95, 69, 42], [79, 59, 34], [103, 87, 64], [128, 115, 96], [107, 97, 85], 2889, [87, 80, 74], [83, 75, 72], [91, 81, 80], [95, 85, 84], [103, 88, 91], 3891, 3893, [111, 98, 105], [116, 103, 113], [120, 107, 116], [127, 115, 119], [125, 113, 113], [122, 110, 112], [120, 108, 108], 50, 48, 48, 50, 153, 2883, 730, 1820, [88, 80, 67], [99, 91, 78], 2278, [84, 76, 63], [95, 87, 74], [96, 88, 75], [67, 59, 46], [34, 26, 13], [29, 19, 10], [39, 28, 22], [40, 29, 23], 4017, [47, 34, 26], [51, 38, 29], [60, 44, 31], [73, 56, 38], [96, 76, 52], [118, 94, 68], 2261, [163, 130, 99], [191, 152, 121], [219, 178, 148], [231, 185, 159], [225, 180, 151], [228, 183, 152], [230, 185, 154], [234, 189, 158], [235, 190, 159], [234, 190, 161], [235, 191, 162], 2456, [240, 196, 167], [239, 198, 170], [241, 200, 172], [243, 203, 177], [250, 210, 184], [255, 216, 190], 2850, [255, 218, 192], [252, 215, 189], [249, 211, 188], [250, 212, 189], 4048, 3448, [240, 202, 179], [237, 199, 176], [239, 198, 176], [238, 200, 177], [245, 204, 182], 3448, [250, 209, 187], [248, 210, 187], [247, 209, 186], 4060, 4049, [252, 214, 191], [247, 209, 188], 3263, [243, 206, 187], [247, 215, 194], 2958, [255, 237, 215], [255, 242, 219], [255, 242, 216], 4071, [255, 236, 209], 3871, 3974, [234, 200, 173], 3050, [236, 199, 172], [158, 124, 96], [96, 70, 43], [68, 48, 23], [78, 62, 39], [121, 108, 89], 826, 3305, 219, 3887, [88, 78, 77], [93, 83, 82], [102, 87, 90], [105, 90, 93], [106, 93, 100], [113, 100, 107], [125, 112, 122], [135, 122, 132], [138, 127, 135], 637, [148, 137, 145], 636, 2085, 2085, 49, 49, 2277, 2502, 2378, [87, 80, 64], 2378, 2280, 4107, 2184, [92, 85, 69], [89, 82, 66], [61, 54, 38], 4015, 4016, [38, 27, 21], 4018, 4018, [48, 35, 29], [49, 36, 27], [55, 39, 26], [65, 48, 30], [98, 77, 56], [117, 93, 67], [141, 111, 83], [164, 130, 102], [192, 153, 124], [217, 176, 146], [229, 183, 157], [226, 180, 154], 3830, [223, 178, 147], [226, 181, 150], 3932, 4037, 3938, [243, 199, 170], [244, 200, 171], [238, 197, 169], [240, 199, 171], [245, 205, 179], [251, 211, 185], [255, 215, 189], 4044, [253, 216, 190], 2849, [255, 214, 192], [254, 212, 190], [250, 208, 186], [244, 202, 180], [240, 195, 174], [236, 191, 170], [235, 190, 169], 4154, [239, 194, 173], [241, 196, 175], [243, 198, 177], 4158, [240, 198, 176], 4160, [243, 201, 179], [246, 204, 182], [244, 199, 176], [244, 202, 178], [246, 205, 183], [247, 211, 187], 3950, [248, 218, 192], [245, 219, 194], [243, 219, 193], [236, 212, 186], [246, 220, 195], [254, 227, 200], 3851, [233, 201, 176], [236, 202, 175], [232, 196, 170], [187, 153, 126], [105, 79, 52], [70, 50, 25], [67, 51, 28], [105, 92, 75], [117, 107, 95], 157, [95, 88, 82], [86, 78, 75], [90, 80, 79], 3889, [106, 92, 92], [109, 94, 97], [108, 96, 100], [115, 102, 109], [127, 114, 123], [137, 124, 134], [145, 133, 145], [154, 144, 155], [161, 149, 161], [157, 147, 158], 2303, 2303, 2277, 2277, 2303, 2501, 2184, 2784, 2184, [86, 79, 63], 2502, 2502, [88, 81, 65], 2085, [52, 45, 29], [35, 27, 14], [34, 24, 15], [42, 31, 25], [43, 32, 28], [41, 30, 24], [45, 32, 26], [44, 31, 23], 2674, [66, 49, 31], [96, 75, 54], [112, 88, 62], [138, 108, 80], [166, 132, 104], [195, 156, 127], [214, 173, 145], [225, 179, 155], [225, 179, 153], [227, 182, 153]]
[150, 100]
```

As you can see, it has both `integer` and `list` values. Then, I pass the **file** into my `image_decoding.py` **script**. Here's how it looks:

```
# imports

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# decoding

f = open("image_code.txt", "r")
Lines = f.readlines()
size = Lines[1].strip('][').split(', ')
image_coding = Lines[0][:-2].strip('][').split(', ')
size[0], size[1] = int(size[0]), int(size[1])
f.close()

print('started reshaping the list')

for i in range(len(image_coding)):
    try:
        value = image_coding[i]
        if value[0] == '[':
            image_coding[i] = [int(image_coding[i][1:]), int(
                image_coding[i + 1]), int(image_coding[i + 2][:-1])]
        if i != 0 and type(image_coding[i - 1]) != list and type(image_coding[i]) != list:
            try:
                image_coding[i] = int(image_coding[i])
            except ValueError:
                pass

    except IndexError:
        break

counter = 1

for j in image_coding:
    if type(j) != int and j[-1] == ']':
        image_coding.remove(j)

    print(
        f'Stage 1: {counter} / {len(image_coding)} ({str(counter / len(image_coding) * 100)[:7]}%) done', end='\r')
    counter += 1

counter = 1

for l in image_coding:
    if type(l) == str:
        image_coding.remove(l)

    print(
        f'Stage 2: {counter} / {len(image_coding)} ({str(counter / len(image_coding) * 100)[:7]}%) done', end='\r')
    counter += 1

print('started decoding')

i = 0

image = []

for pixel in image_coding:

    i += 1

    print(f'Decoding: {str(i / len(image_coding) * 100)[:7]}% done', end='\r')

    if type(pixel) == list:
        image.append(pixel)
    else:
        image.append(image_coding[pixel])

# unflattening the image to display it correctly

print('\nstarted unflattening')

new_image = []

for i in range(size[0]):
    imageline = []
    for j in range(size[1]):
        imageline.append(image[i*size[1] + j])
    new_image.append(imageline)

image = new_image

plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

When running the script on the `50x100.jpg` image (which looks like this):

[image: 50x100 image]

The code **works flawlessly**. However, when I try to run it with the `100x100.jpg` image, `100x150.jpg` image or `300x200.jpg` image, which look like this:

[image: 100x100 image]

[image: 100x150 image]

[image: 300x200 image]

`image_decoding.py` returns the following `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\pc\Desktop\Programming\imageCoding\image_decoding.py", line 82, in <module>
    plt.imshow(image)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper        
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2611, in imshow
    __ret = gca().imshow(
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\_api\deprecation.py", line 454, in wrapper        
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1423, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 5572, in imshow
    im.set_data(X)
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 701, in set_data
    raise TypeError("Image data of dtype {} cannot be converted to "
TypeError: Image data of dtype object cannot be converted to float
```

**P. S.** There might be some really stupid bug in the code (e.g. missing bracket), I'm still quite new to this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite a lot of code you have there... I hope my answer is clear without reposting everything :)

Your bug is in the file reading and parsing (recreating the original data-types etc.), so I have the following suggestion for you.

Python comes with a package called pickle that you can use to store python objects and read them back into memory.

I'd suggest the following changes to your code.

In image_encoding.py replace

```
f = open("image_code.txt", "w")
f.write(str(image_coding))
f.close()
f = open("image_code.txt", "a")
f.write(f'\n{size}')
f.close()
```

with

```
import pickle  # put that at the top of your file
with open("image_code.txt", "wb") as file:
    pickle.dump({"image_coding": image_coding, "size": size}, file)
```

And then in image_decoding.py instead of

```
f = open("image_code.txt", "r")
Lines = f.readlines()
size = Lines[1].strip('][').split(', ')
image_coding = Lines[0][:-2].strip('][').split(', ')
size[0], size[1] = int(size[0]), int(size[1])
f.close()

print('started reshaping the list')

for i in range(len(image_coding)):
    try:
        value = image_coding[i]
        if value[0] == '[':
            image_coding[i] = [int(image_coding[i][1:]), int(
                image_coding[i + 1]), int(image_coding[i + 2][:-1])]
        if i != 0 and type(image_coding[i - 1]) != list and type(image_coding[i]) != list:
            try:
                image_coding[i] = int(image_coding[i])
            except ValueError:
                pass

    except IndexError:
        break
```

you can use:

```
import pickle
with open("test_data/image_code.txt", "rb") as file:
    data = pickle.load(file)
size = data.get("size")
image_coding = data.get("image_coding")
```

and have your original variables back without checking for "[" and casting back to integers etc.

Hope that helps. If you have any question, dont hesitate to ask.